# Permutation test for adonis under NA model?

Tags: r, vegan

I am having issues understanding why the permanova computed with `adonis2()` in `vegan` is returning a `NA model` in the second test that you find below.

The toy example reproduces the error but I am not 100% sure that the reason why the toy is behaving weird is the same reason why the actual data show the same error. However, the data are very similar, i.e. a count matrix, the metadata are comparable, i.e. treatments and sites, and the formula is the same.

```
library("vegan")

# create metadata
meta <- cbind.data.frame(sampleID = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"), treatment = c("c", "w", "c", "w", "c"), site = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2"))

# create counts
counts <- data.frame(s1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), s2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), s3 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), s4 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), s5 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0))
rownames(counts) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")

# reproducing adonis issue
transposed_taxa <- t(counts)

# set seed
set.seed(321)

# using adonis2 to perform the analysis

# set number of permutations
perm <- how(nperm = 999)

# run adonis ~treatment+site
# returns a reduced model
adonis2(transposed_taxa~treatment+site, data=meta, permutations=perm, method="bray", by="margin")

# run adonis ~treatment
# returns a NA model
adonis2(transposed_taxa~treatment, data=meta, permutations=perm, method="bray", by="margin")
```

Why is the second test returning a NA model and is that a problem?

Edit after comment

This is what I get as output:

```
> adonis2(transposed_taxa~treatment+site, data=meta, permutations=perm, method="bray", by="margin")

'nperm' >= set of all permutations: complete enumeration.
Set of permutations < 'minperm'. Generating entire set.
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Marginal effects of terms
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 119

adonis2(formula = transposed_taxa ~ treatment + site, data = meta, permutations = perm, method = "bray", by = "margin")
          Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)
treatment  1  0.07628 0.10414 0.4585 0.7000
site       1  0.28743 0.39242 1.7276 0.3167
Residual   2  0.33275 0.45429              
Total      4  0.73246 1.00000

> adonis2(transposed_taxa~treatment, data=meta, permutations=perm, method="bray", by="margin")

'nperm' >= set of all permutations: complete enumeration.
Set of permutations < 'minperm'. Generating entire set.
Permutation test for adonis under NA model
Marginal effects of terms
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 119

adonis2(formula = transposed_taxa ~ treatment, data = meta, permutations = perm, method = "bray", by = "margin")
          Df SumOfSqs     R2      F Pr(>F)
treatment  1  0.11228 0.1533 0.5431    0.7
Residual   3  0.62018 0.8467              
Total      4  0.73246 1.0000
```

In the second example, you can see how I get the NA model: `Permutation test for adonis under NA model`:

```
'nperm' >= set of all permutations: complete enumeration. 
Set of permutations < 'minperm'. Generating entire set.
Permutation test for adonis under NA model
```

In the first example there is nothing weird since I get a reduced model.

I am not sure it may help, but here you can find version of packages I am using:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] vegan_2.6-2     lattice_0.20-45 permute_0.9-7  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-57    compiler_4.2.0 Matrix_1.4-1   parallel_4.2.0 tools_4.2.0   
 [6] mgcv_1.8-40    splines_4.2.0  nlme_3.1-157   grid_4.2.0     cluster_2.1.3
```

Comment: What do  you mean with a NA model? When I copy-pasted your example I got just an ordinary model with P-value of 0.7 (and F=0.5431).

Comment: @JariOksanen, I added further info plus the output I get, to show what I mean by NA model.

Comment: Confirmed. Fixed in https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan.

Comment: so, was it a kind of bug, right? then, you or I can add an answer and close the question.

Comment: and, by the way, I installed the new version and it works. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to ignoring the case where users apply marginal tests for one-variable models. Marginal models test significances of each variable after all other variables, and if there is only one explanatory variable, this is an empty model. Empty models are just skipped, and we set the permutation model `NA` when we did no permutation.

In addition to `adonis2`, this also concerns permutational `anova` models for constrained ordination with only one explanatory variable.

This is fixed in github version of vegan.